# Multiple category formatting buttons hopping at the same time as other categories

Tags: bug, markdown, editing-help

Should the formatting stop jumping when clicking on another formatting help while jumping is running on another category?

Comment: They only bounce for ~5 seconds. And their height decreases quickly. So this is pretty easy to cope with if you just wait 1 or 2 seconds between clicking categories. Also there's only 6 categories, it takes about 12 seconds to click through all of them at that rate, which really doesn't seem that inconvenient (for that rare use case when you're blowing through them).

Comment: If I'm guessing correctly at the root of your problem, btw, it sounds like perhaps a better solution would be to highlight the background of the corresponding help category when you mouse over one of the buttons in that category. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds to me like you want a way to quickly determine which category to read, given a button.